# How to render offscreen SkyBoxEntity

Tags: c++, qt5, render, qt3d

I created skybox and it works great for me, but when I turn camera from the center it disappear, I understand that it's because my skybox transformation is (0,0,0) and when I'm not looking at that point it won't render offscreen items.
Maybe there're some variable to let entity render offscreen, or I need to write extra script?
Here's my code for better understanding:

```
    Qt3DExtras::QSkyboxEntity *skyboxEntity = new Qt3DExtras::QSkyboxEntity(resultEntity);
    skyboxEntity->setBaseName("qrc:/res/skybox");
    skyboxEntity->setExtension(".tga");

    const float baseScale = 0.1f;

    Qt3DCore::QTransform *skyTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform(skyboxEntity);
    skyTransform->setTranslation(QVector3D(0.0f, baseScale / 8.0f - 0.001f, 0.0f ));
    skyTransform->setScale3D(QVector3D(1, 1, 1));

    skyboxEntity->addComponent(skyTransform);
```

Answer (score 0):

3D objects that are not in the [viewing frustum](https://learnopengl.com/Guest-Articles/2021/Scene/Frustum-Culling) won't be rendered by the Graphics Pipeline and that's the default behavior for performance reasons.

However, the [following message](https://interest.qt-project.narkive.com/G0rgONE1/qt3d-face-culling#post2) discusses how *face culling* can be disabled in the frame graph of the scene:

> Instead of adding the CullFace to the materials, you can also add it to the framegraph. Take a copy of the ForwardRenderer.qml framegraph (if you're using that) and add a `StateSet` (`RenderStateSet` in Qt 5.7+) to the tree containing the `CullFaceState` and you will also need to add in a `DepthTest` state object too since we are replacing Qt3D's default state.
>
> See [QTBUG-51770](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51770) and my comment there.
>
> Cheers,
> Sean